# Printing an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Reports are viewed in a bespoke web application and should then be printable.  When the print icon is clicked the print preview shows an entirely different report.  The iframe id seems to be held as a variable and after looking at numerous examples I cannot find any examples like this.  Can anyone suggest a solution?  Please note I did not write the original code but have been asked to find a solution.

This is the function:

```js
function printReport(printFrameId) {
  if (window.frames[printFrameId].innerHTML != "") {
    window.frames[printFrameId].focus();
    window.frames[printFrameId].print();
  } else {
    setTimeout(printReport,1000);
  }     
}
```

```
<div id="reportContent" style="padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px;">
        <?php
        $reportsViewFind = mysql_query($reportSQL);
        $z = 0;
        while($reportView = mysql_fetch_array($reportsViewFind))
        {
            $z++;
            if(empty($reportView["reports_view"]))
            {
                echo '<div id="'.$reportView["reports_run"].'BOX" class="dBox" hidden>
                <h2>PLJ Report</h2>
                <h3>'.$reportView["reports_section"].': '.$reportView["reports_description"].'</h3>
                <div class="errorbox"><b>FAILED REPORT:</b><br>ERROR: Compiler not completed<br>Failed on <a>'.$date.'</a><br><b>0</b> Results</div>
                </div>';
            }
            else 
            {
                if($reportsFilter == "all") { $reportsFrame = $reportView["reports_view"]; } else { $reportsFrame = substr($reportView["reports_view"],0,-4)."_c.php?centre=".$reportsFilter; }
                eval($reportView["reports_view"]);
                echo '<div id="'.$reportView["reports_run"].'BOX" class="dBox" hidden>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/print.png" alt="Print" width="24" height="24" style="float:right;padding-right:10px;margin-top:-30px;" onclick="printReport(\''.$z.'\');" /></a>
                <h2>PLJ Report</h2>
                <h3>'.$reportView["reports_section"].': '.$reportView["reports_description"].'</h3><iframe id="'.$z.'" name="'.$z.'" src="includes/reports/'.$reportsFrame.'" seamless></iframe></div>';
            }
            if($staffdata["staff_type_id"] < 3)
            {
                echo '<div id="'.$reportView["reports_run"].'COM" class="dBox" hidden>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/print.png" alt="Print" width="24" height="24" style="float:right;padding-right:10px;margin-top:-30px;" onclick="printReport(\''.$z.'c\');" /></a>
                <h2>PLJ Comparison</h2>
                <h3>'.$reportView["reports_section"].': '.$reportView["reports_description"].'</h3><iframe id="'.$z.'c" name="'.$z.'c" src="includes/reports/comparison.php?report='.$reportView["reports_id"].'" seamless></iframe></div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
        <div id="missing" class="dBox" style="color:red;" hidden>
        <h2>PLJ Report</h2>
        <h3>Report Error</h3>
        <p>An error occurred when gathering the information for this report. Please close this report and try again.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="missing2" class="dBox" style="color:red;" hidden>
        <h2>PLJ Report</h2>
        <h3>Comparison Error</h3>
        <p>An error occurred when gathering the information for this comparison. Please close this comparison and try again.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?
The code you have is working, see this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/yr4ch6t4/

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your reply.  The function actually works as a report is displayed in the print preview, but it is not the same as the one viewed on the screen.  For example Report 1 is viewed on the screen and Report 3 appears in the print preview.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue.  The code you've posted is working, and you haven't given enough information to solve this.

Comment: Hi Adam, I have added the full <div> above and yes I know this is very old mysql.  There are a total of 12 reports in the database.

Comment: @JanTay I don't see any iFrame in the code you have provided. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Lelio, look for $z which I think is where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @JanTay Please provide the relevant code, including the iframe.  Give us something that recreates the issue in a js fiddle, codepen, or similar.

Comment: @JanTay `$z` doesn't seem to be an issue, its just a counter iterating over the results.  The JS parameter that your PHP is setting may be the issue.  `window.frames[printFrameId].print();` is expecting `printFrameId` to be an integer, but your passing it `printReport(\''.$z.'c\');`, e.g. `2c`.

Comment: Hi Adam, I think you may have hit on something there but this is not causing the problem as all the 'c' reports print fine.  It is actually a problem with the src.  In the 'c' reports the scr finds the report id from the database and that is used as the integer.  In the non 'c' reports the scr does not find the report id from the database but just the name of the php page.  Therefore, the iframe finds the nearest 'c' report and prints that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all those that posted possible solutions but the issue is now solved.  I removed the print icon from the iframe page as that did not work.  I put a print icon on the php page and used a  with Java Script to print what was required instead.  This works a treat.